# Using a .txt file to input dataset into a vector (potentially more than one of dataset) in C++

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

I am working on this project for school that uses JNI and C++ together. The java code was given to me, it gets the user to enter 6 different inputs for a data set regarding a zoo animal. At the end it will ask Y or N if you want to add another.

If yes the input will be on a second line, once N is selected it will write to a .txt file and the format will be:

001235 Alita            Mammal           Wolf             0 0

001234 Bob              Mammal           Wolf             0 0

(please note there is not an empty line in between the two data)

The code below is what I wrote to open the file and get the inputs into vectors which works successfully for one line of user inputs. I am running into the issue of how to I make this work logically for a potential unknown amount of vectors a user could enter.

```
void LoadDataFromFile()
{
     /*
            TODO: Write proper code to load data from input file (generated using JNI) into vector/array.
     */

    
    vector<string> zooVector(6);
    int count = 0;
    unsigned int i;

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("zoodata.txt");

    if (!inputFile) {
        cerr << "Unable to open file zoodata.txt";
        exit(1);   // call system to stop
    }


    while(count < 6)  {
        for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            inputFile >> zooVector.at(i);
            count += 1;
        }
    }
```

The ultimate goal will be to write this to memory for a multi-class inheritance but I am trying to get the inputs to work for the vectors.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.  Do you get any errors or do you have a specific programming question?

Comment: No errors just a question. The question was  I am running into the issue of how do I make this work logically for a potential unknown amount of vectors a user could enter. The current code is set up to  only get 6 vectors, based on 1 line of 6 inputs. The user can potentially enter a limitless amount of data sets (lines) with 6 input per line.

Comment: Logically you have to change the number of iterations. You could use `while(true)` and leave the loop with `break` after a stop condition.

Comment: You should set up a `struct` or `class` to model one line of the input data.  This will help simplify your code.  Add an overload of `operator>>` to your struct.

Comment: This is the first time ever working with fstream and text files from inputs, I had to do research to find the proper code to even open and close .txt files. The instructor pretty much just threw us in the pool with this one. What do you recommend the IF statement be to continue the while loop or breaking based on if there is more lines of data or not?

Comment: You could ask the user for a choice after each input. You could use a sentinel input to end. The user could use EOF to end input. There are many ways.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a vector of strings for the different fields of the `animal`; you need a `struct`.

THEN you'd need a vector of those `struct`s to represent a zoo; it will grow dynamically as you read more lines from your file.